# Polymer - animating content within paper

Tags: polymer, material-design

I'm trying to learn Polymer. Currently, I have a custom element that needs to animate content within some paper. In an attempt to do this, I currently have the following:

```
<paper-material elevation="4">
  <h4>Hello</h4>

  <neon-animated-pages selected="0" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">                         
    <div>
      Thank you for visiting. I think you'll enjoy what you're
      gonna find. To dive in, click the "Next" button.
      <br />
      <paper-button>Next</paper-button>
    </div>

    <div>
      some more information
    </div>                          
  </neon-animated-pages>
</paper-material>
```

The odd part is, the content within the `neon-animated-pages` element does not render within the paper properly. I've included a screenshot below showing how it renders. [image: picture]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of [`neon-animated-pages`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/blob/master/neon-animated-pages.html), you will see that it is a `position: relative` div, and its children (the pages) are all `position: absolute` (taken out of the document flow).

This means that unless you give a height to your `neon-animated-pages` element (either by directly setting the `height` CCS property or the `fit`or `flex` class), you will see some overflow like this.